# `org-bullets` - No longer needed

Tags: org-mode, package, package-repositories

For a while, I've been getting the message

```
Package menu: Operationfinished. 1 package no longer needed, type 'M-x package-autoremove' to remove them
```

The package is `org-bullets`, very spread package through the community (it's what I've seen)... So, I thought that (perhaps) it was included into the `org-plus-contrib` branch (or even the `org` itself). Thus, I ran the command!... and the bullets were gone!!!

Of course, I installed the package again and problem solved, but everytime I update or install a package I'm getting the same message over and over.

Can someone explain me what happen to `org-bullets`? And whether I can get rid off the message (without dropping the package) or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install a package that requires another package, the package manager will install both. If you remove the first package, or in an update its requirements change so that it no longer depends on the second package, the second one is no longer 'required'. Emacs doesn't automatically remove it, but does give you the warning message so that you can remove it if you want (via `M-x package-autoremove`.

You can tell Emacs that you actually want this package to remain by adding it to the variable `package-selected-packages`, via `M-x customize-variable package-selected-packages`.